# working with memcpy for buffers

Tags: c, buffer

I am trying to create a buffer of characters as shown:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
struct gvk{
  char a ;
  char b ;
  char c ;
};

int main(){
  char *buf;
  struct gvk k = {'A','B','C'};

  memcpy(buf, &k , 3*sizeof(char));
  printf("values in buf is %s\n",buf);
}
```

But my program is exiting saying "exited with non-zero status"
Where did I do wrong?

Comment: `char buf[4];`... `sprintf(buf, "%c%c%c", k.a, k.b, k.c);`

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the `buf` and also terminate it with a `\0` if you want to use `%s` to print. Moreover it is not a good idea to assume that `sizeof(gvk)` is 3 bytes.

Comment: Read more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and work hard to avoid it. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Learn to use the debugger (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collegue upper told you to allocate memory dynamically but since its much more **error-prone**, **harder to work with** (need to free memory) then with automatic arrays + **you know the size in compile time**, there is no reason to use dynamic allocation. I would recommend you to use automatic array instead. Also dont forget for one byte for null-terminating character.

```
char buf[4];
```

We are using dynamic allocation just if there is no other way. Even if you didnt know size of array in compile time, since [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) you may use [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)'s.

---

Also compiler **may** add padding between/behind struct elements. Padding [aligns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) structure members to "natural" address boundaries.

In your case it would *probably look like this*

```
struct gvk{
  char a ;   // 1B
  char b ;   // 1B
  char c ;   // 1B
             // 1B padding
};
```

Which means in this case it should work well, anyway you should avoid using `memcpy(buf, &k , 3*sizeof(char));` on structures like this, because you might copy padding instead of real element of structure.

---

Also there is no need to explicitly type `sizeof(char)` which, by standard, has size 1 (B).

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory before using `buf` otherwise it is undefined behaviour.

You should declare it like this(Dynamically):

```
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
```

Comment: Also the string terminator if he wants to use `%s` for printing

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1 by definition